# MongoDB find based on sub collection

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

my data is structured as below:

Basically it contains Way Point information from google distance matrix. i need to find the routes that start from point C and ending at point E. if i use $and operator and query for

```
db.Routes.find( {
    $and : [
        {routes.legs.start_address:"C"},
        {routes.legs.end_address:"E"}
    ]
}
```

I still get both this results. what are the possible approaches do i have for to resolve this. I'm trying Mongo for the first time so any help or guidance is much appreciated.

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "596e004151cc92046c28dd39"
    },
    "routes": [
      {
        "legs": [
          {
            "end_address": "B",
            "start_address": "A"
          },
          {
            "end_address": "C",
            "start_address": "B"
          },
          {
            "end_address": "D",
            "start_address": "C"
          },
          {
            "end_address": "E",
            "start_address": "D"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "status": "OK",
    "Date": {
      "$date": "2017-07-18T12:34:07.781Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "596e007d51cc9231a8117607"
    },
    "routes": [
      {
        "legs": [
          {
            "end_address": "E",
            "start_address": "F"
          },
          {
            "end_address": "D",
            "start_address": "E"
          },
          {
            "end_address": "C",
            "start_address": "D"
          },
          {
            "end_address": "B",
            "start_address": "C"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "status": "OK",
    "Date": {
      "$date": "2017-07-18T12:35:09.121Z"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: If you are looking for a query that calculates the path and filter the result, you expect too much from the DB. The best thing you can do is to fetch subset of the documents where start address and end address match, then analyse them on application level.

Comment: Expected result is to return the first item only.

Comment: @AlexBlex Nope i'm trying to see if we could query based on the criteria and the sequence of the sub collection to find out the result. nothing to do with paths

Comment: non-numerical sequence of elements identified by start and end address sounds like a path to me. You are asking to build a directed graph for each document runtime and filter by a segment, if you prefer such wording. Independently on terminology it's way too complex.

Comment: I think when you say 'sequence', you mean the index of the array. Your query return all routes that have `start_address:"C"` and `end_address:"E"` anywhere in a leg. You will have to write code to filter the query result on condition `end_address:"E"` comes after index of `start_address:"C"` in your server.

Comment: @ShabinMuhammed could you please explain a little bit more.

Comment: I could, if you explain your requirement a bit more clearly. What are you trying to achieve ? You said 'Expected result is to return the first item only'. How is that ?

Comment: @ShabinMuhammed basically there are list of routes like this and i would like to get only trips that could go from C to E not vice versa. when i use $and it returns both.

Comment: You will have to handle that logic in your program. You can't have that level of logic in a MongoDB query